# Gatsby fast-refresh when transitioning yarn workspace boundaries

Tags: gatsby

I'm using Gatsby in a yarn monorepo that imports react components and sass from a different yarn workspace. The problem is that fast-refresh doesn't work when importing files from the second workspace. Assuming that gatsby is in the @scope/gatsby package, and the components and scss are in @scope/components:

file: @scope/gatsby/src/styles/app.scss

```
@import '@scope/components/sass/components.scss'
```

I don't get any fast-reloading when I change files in @scope/components. Instead, I have to run `gatsby develop` after every change I make. Is this a feature that gatsby can support, or do I have to amend the babel or webpack configurations to get hot reloading? If so, what config do I change?

It works if I do:

```
@import '../../../components/sass/components.scss';
```

but that makes it less clear that these imports are coming from a different package.